# How can I mount remove /dev/mem to local

Tags: mount, memory, devices, sshfs

This question is relate to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45509), but more general.

Currently I mount remote root by sshfs

```
sshfs -o sshfs_sync,sync_readdir,reconnect,follow_symlinks,direct_io,sync_read root@pi:/ pi
```

`/proc` is ok, but /dev/mem is not works

```
head pi/dev/mem
head: error reading 'pi/dev/mem': Operation not permitted
```

So,how can I mount remote `/dev/mem` to local

**EDIT**

I want to control raspberry pi from my dev laptop, it will be way easier if I can just run program from my laptop by mount remote `/dev/mem`.

Currently I mount raspberry by sshfs, the dev loop like

```
# Compile from my laptop is way faster
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOBIN=`pwd`/bin go install main.go
cp bin/main /path/to/mounted/pi
# Then run from pi
```

If I can mount `/dev/mem`, the dev loop will become

```
go run main.go # dev
go run main.go # dev
go run main.go # dev
# Good to go
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOBIN=`pwd`/bin go install main.go
cp bin/main /path/to/mounted/pi
```

this will save a lot time, and I can do debug from my local.

Also I think mount `/dev/mem` only cost a few of network, and I found [Network device](https://github.com/yoe/nbd) can mount remote device, but I can not compile due to docbook2man.

Comment: sshfs is implemented via sftp which can only transfer files, whereas `/dev/mem` is a device. The files under `/proc` are still files, not devices, even though they are implemented by the kernel.

Comment: How can I mount remote device ?

Comment: You're attempting to read from the memory of the machine where the process is running: a device file is just a number that tells the kernel what to run. To do what you want to do, a remote filesystem isn't enough, you'd need a process that relays memory accesses. I can't think of an existing program offhand. Are you sure that's what you want? It would be very slow. Why not run the program on the remote machine? [What problem are you trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?